# Android Database Example

Tags: android, database

I did android database example. I can create database and add value. But I cant show my value of database. I took nullpoint error. My codes are [here](https://gist.github.com/germanboy/9621851)

Comment: You cannot instantiate an Activity like this - MainActivity m1=new MainActivity();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot instantiate an Activity like this

```
MainActivity m1=new MainActivity();
```

Hence you're getting the `NullPointerException`. Also, you should refer [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#db) to learn how to store and retrieve databases. Also refer [this](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/databases.html).

**EDIT**

You just need to create another object of the DB helper class - in your case, the `veritabani` class. Create it in the other activity.
You don't need to use it like this

```
SQLiteDatabase db=m1.v1.getReadableDatabase();
```

Rather, just create another object in the 2nd activity and read.

```
veritabani objInTabTwo = new veritabani(this);
objInTabTwo.getReadableDatabase();
...
```

The contents written in previous activity can be read the next time it is read since the same database is being accessed by both objects.

**Sidenote**

Also, if I may, it isn't a good practice using public member variables. Keep them private and access them via public methods.

Comment: Thank you for answer. Buy i dont understand. I have 2 tab menu. And i create database on tab1 menu. Than i want to show values on tab2. How can i do it ?

Comment: Where are you getting the error? Post logcat and point to the line as well.

Comment: i did like it,
private veritabani obj; 
obj = new veritabani(this);

i gettin error for "obj = new veritabani(this);"

nullpoint error

Comment: Oh great. Edit your question and post the solution in EDIT so that anybody who visits this later would know what to do. :)